# Streaming Clusters Data in different regions into a single Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

We are having different clusters in different regions and we are trying the push all of that cluster data into a single event hub.

1. Is this possible? If yes will the event hub be able to handle the data volume and what are the best practices to push the data effectively.
2. If not possible do we need to have separate event hub for each cluster to stream the data.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Eventhubs throughout is measured by TU. 1TU allows for ingress of 1 MB or 1000 events per second which ever occurs first. There are some nice examples [HERE](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-event-hub-understanding-designing-partitions-unit-kamal-pathak/).
So depending on the expected volume of ingestion you will need to set the throughput to the correct value. There is no limitation in Eventhubs from receiving data from different regions.

To make use of the full throughput, you should set the number of partitions to its max which is 32. This means you can have a maximum of 32 simultaneous receivers on the eventhub and each processes its respective partition.
For example, if your eventhub is triggering azure functions, you can have max number of function instances as the number of partitions. If you set only 1 partition, then only one function instances/server is possible and your processing speed will go down.
You can read more about partitions [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability#partitions).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism to stream data from an ADX cluster into an Event Hub, so you either don't mean ADX or have an orchestration setup that reads data from ADX and pushes it to Event Hub.
In addition to the previous answer, please note, that high-rate cross-region writes into Event Hubs could increase latency.